# How can i update the text of more than one label with the same class name using the input blur event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working in a project and i have to update the text of a label when the focus is losed in the input
This is the html part:

```
<input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" class="inputName"/>
<input id="MidName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" class="inputName"/>
<input id="LastName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" class="inputName"/>
<p class="passengerTitle1">hola</p>
<input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" class="inputName"/>
<input id="MidName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" class="inputName"/>
<input id="LastName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" class="inputName"/>
<p class="passengerTitle1">hola</p>
```

and the js code of firing the blur event of the inputs is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      fullName = '';
      $(".inputName").blur(
          function (event) {
            var name = $(this).val();
            fullName += name+ ' ';
            $(".passengerTitle1").text(fullName);
         }
      );
  });
```

I get the following result:
the text of both labels: Phellip E. Summer Edgar B. Thompson

But the expected result is :
for the first label Phellip E. Summer
for the second label Edgar B. Thompson

this is the jsfiddle link:[jsfiddle lin](http://jsfiddle.net/naufal07/zavw8h56/)

I wonder for a little help because it a very important project and don't want to miss the deadline of the project. 
cheers.

Comment: Can you post your actual javascript? What you posted doesn't match the issue you say you have.

Comment: The issue is because you have the same class name for label. There are couple more issues as well. You need to have different class name for different passenger else your label is going to be messed up. Blur event adds to the damage. try having different class names and append the names only if the value is present.

Comment: how do i check if the value is present or not, my knowledge of js is limited. cheers.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zavw8h56/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have proposed solutions by changing the `html`, I'm proposing a solution to implement this without changing the `html` (if you want to stick to your current `html`).

Use [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/) and [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/) like this:

```
$(this).nextAll(".passengerTitle1").first().text(fullName);
```

Implemented on your fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bardhlohaj/zavw8h56/1/)

But you also have another problem, where you are not properly setting the `fullName` variable.

Again, if you don't want to change the `html`, you could solve it using [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) like this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bardhlohaj/zavw8h56/3/)

Comment: This is near to what i know, how can i reset the fullName variable properly because now the second label has the value of the first appended to what i write in the other fields.

Comment: added the solution for the second problem in another `JSFiddle`.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to make some changes in your html.
I hope this is what you want to achieve.

```js
$(".inputName").on("blur", function() {
  var inputName = $(this).parent(".passengerInfo").children(".inputName");
  var outputName = "";
  $(inputName).each(function() {
    outputName += $(this).val() + " ";
  })


  $(this).parent(".passengerInfo").children(".passengerTitle1").text(outputName)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="passengerInfo">
  <input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" class="inputName" />
  <input id="MidName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" class="inputName" />
  <input id="LastName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" class="inputName" />
  <p class="passengerTitle1">hola</p>
</div>
<div class="passengerInfo">
  <input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" class="inputName" />
  <input id="MidName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" class="inputName" />
  <input id="LastName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" class="inputName" />
  <p class="passengerTitle1">hola</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".inputName").blur(
      function (event) {
        var titel = getPassengerTitel($(this)); // find the titel element
        var fullName = getName(titel); // read Fullname by titel element
        titel.html(fullName);
     }
  );
```

});

```
function getName(passengerTitelElem){
 var last = passengerTitelElem.prev();
 var middel = last.prev();
 var first = middel.prev();
 var name ='';
 if(first.val()) name += first.val() + ' ';
 if(middel.val()) name += middel.val() + ' ';
 if(last.val()) name += last.val() + ' ';
 return name;
```

}

```
function getPassengerTitel(e) {
 var next = e.next();
 if(next.attr('class') == 'passengerTitle1') {
      return next;
 }
 return getPassengerTitel(next);
```

}